# "Do I need "has" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> There’s only one feeling that (has) never helped anyone: hate.

Do I need the "has"? Why or why not?

Note: On [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=kAcDWpCEIYGm8QW3j58w&q=%22There%E2%80%99s%20only%20one%20feeling%20that%20%20%22&oq=%22There%E2%80%99s%20only%20one%20feeling%20that%20%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l4.1360.1360.0.1433.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.4M2jrhhmy84) I find more versions without the "has", but I'm still not very sure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences mean roughly the same thing.

However, by inserting "has" you make clear that hate hasn't helped anyone *at any time in the past.*

Without "has" you *could* be stating that *within the context of a certain time period (say, over the course of a person's time in a given location)* hate never helped. That being said, without 'has', if there's no implied context of the kind I described, it means the same thing.